# How to run MATLAB file when it is already open using a batch file?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to find a CMD code to run a MATLAB file but when MATLAB is already running (I don't want to open MATLAB again in different window).

I'm using this code:

```
matlab -nosplash -r run('C:\xampp\htdocs\RCE\FYP_expirement\SpeedControl\exp1_start.m');
```

But every time this code is executed (from a batch file), it opens MATLAB again in a separate window.

Comment: It is easier to control everything from MATLAB. Instead of writing a batch script that repeatedly calls MATLAB, write a MATLAB script that calls other programs.

Comment: Hello @CrisLuengo , iam actully going to use this in certain  PHP page of my website that when a user click on a button this batch file will be executed to run MATLAB file and return somthing to the user. Now it is working  fine but it is not efficient to open MATLAB every time a user make request. So anyway, how actually iam going to control things from MATLAB ? or is there any better way to enhance this approach?

Comment: This is the official MATLAB solution: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/web-apps.html . You can also try this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29027-web-server